# Understanding the output of typeid().name()

Tags: c++, types

I was checking some types of variables and got some confusing results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int number = 5;
    int* pointer = &number;

    cout << typeid(number).name() << endl;      // i
    cout << typeid(pointer).name() << endl;     // Pi
    cout << typeid(&pointer).name() << endl;    // PPi

    return 0;
}
```

The `i` means `int`, but what do `Pi` and `PPi` mean? `Pointer int`?

Comment: They don't mean anything in terms of standard C++. I suspect you're using GCC, which uses that system for naming types with `typeid`. If you look at something like MSVC, they'll be different.

Comment: http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html and assuming you are using gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means pointer to an integer and pointer to a pointer to an integer, respectively.

Answer (score 10):

- i: integer
- Pi: pointer to integer variable
- Ppi: pointer to a pointer to integer variable

Comment: Dn : NullPtr (typeid(nullptr).name())