# typeid gives types m, j and Pj

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand a piece of code and came across this

```
    size_t max = 3;
    unsigned trial {3};
    auto* primes { new unsigned[max] };
```

I read that when you define something like `unsigned int trial {3};` you get an `int` that can it's only positive. But this `unsigned` variables doesn't specify the type. So I tried to know what type they are with this:

```
    cout << typeid(max).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(trial).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(primes).name() << endl;
```

But got this weird output

```
m
j
Pj
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the output of typeid().name()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268090/understanding-the-output-of-typeid-name)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name Notes section.

Comment: Use symbol demangler (like c++filt in Linux).

Comment: @KamilCuk handy trick: Tack a #<title of section> onto a cppreference url and you can link right to the section. Never tried it with multiple-word sections so I'm not sure how you specify that, but https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name#Notes links directly to Notes.

Comment: @user4581301 You'd use underscores.

Comment: @HTNW Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned` is short for `unsigned int`.

The strings returned from `typeid::name` are [implementation-specific](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/name/).

Since you seem to be on some Linux system, probably demangling could help you along: [stdc++ demangling](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).